# Aggregating Columns by Neighbourhood

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is a link to the actual data I am working with which can be copy-pasted into Excel to help make things easier.

Link to the actual data --> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11lSHF1pKyFOrjIhf1bWbCggVF1numMsiHBpbfZeTV7A/edit?usp=sharing

The problem: In columns A-F I have data on neighbourhood assaults for quarters 1, 2, and 3. In columns I-K I have column headers that indicate when a house was valued, and I want to fill those columns with the assault data. The contextual reason I am doing this for a research project to value properties as a function of criminal activity in a neighbourhood using some econometric analysis.

What I Need To Do: I need to fill the values of columns I-K with values in the other columns based on the following  reasoning:

"House Valued in Q2": This column needs to be filled with the assault information from the previous quarter, so this is as easy as copying and pasting the assault values from "Quarter 1" with respect to the neighbourhoods on the left.

"House Valued in Q3": This column needs to be filled with the summation of the assault data from "Quarter 1" and "Quarter 2". This is because if the house is being valued in quarter 3, the valuation will incorporate information from the most recent previous quarters.

"House Valued in Q4": This column needs to be filled with the summation of the assault data from "Quarter 1", "Quarter 2", and "Quarter 3". This is because if the house is being valued in quarter 4, the valuation will incorporate information from the most recent previous quarters.

Here is the caveat. It is not the case that every neighbourhood experienced an assault in a given quarter, which is why some neighbourhoods appear in one quarter but not in another. For instance, in the vicinity of Column A Row 6, you'll see that the neighbourhood "Allard" did not experience an assault in Quarter 1, but did experience assaults in quarters 2 and 3. All together, this "master list" consists of all of the neighbourhoods that have experienced at least one assault from quarter 1-3.

I hope that this question is far more specific and clear for those who intend to help.

Comment: The "House Valued in Q" columns need to have their own Neighborhood name. On row 5, there are multiple neighborhoods. There is no way to know which neighborhood the House Valued Q belongs to. In Column H, create a master list of discrete neighbor names (this can be done dynamically with a formula). Now you have a lookup value for columns I, J & K. These rows formulas will look up there rows column H value. The I formula will simply lookup its H row value in Column a and in the row of column a where found it will return the value of column B. Column J: J2=I2+vlook(h2,C:D,2,false).